# Cannot add sidebar near datatables

Tags: css, datatables, bootstrap-4

I'm using `Bootstrap 4` with `Datatables` for jquery. Actually all works well for the `datatables` integration, but I have a little problem with the sidebar. I'm trying to add a sidebar to the left side of the `datatables`, this is the html that I'm using:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#fixtures" role="button"
               class="btn btn-rounded hide-btn btn-sm ml-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="fixtures">
                <i class="mdi mdi-view-agenda"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="card-body collapse show rounded-full-margin" id="fixtures">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3 px-1 bg-dark" id="sticky-sidebar">
                            <div class="py-2 sticky-top">
                                <div class="nav flex-column">
                                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Sidebar</a>
                                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col" id="main">
                            <h4 class="header-title text-center">Matches</h4>
                            <table id="fixtures-datatable" class="table dt-responsive nowrap">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="sorting">League</th>
                                        <th class="sorting">Hour</th>
                                        <th class="sorting text-center">Home</th>
                                        <th class="sorting text-center">Result</th>
                                        <th class="sorting text-center">Away</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>BR,Brazil: Serie B</td>

                                            <td>00:15</td>
                                            <td class="text-right">
                                                Guarani
                                                <img src="https://secure.cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/316.png" height="20" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">0 - 2</td>
                                            <td class="text-left">
                                                <img src="https://secure.cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/307.png" height="20" />
                                                Goi&#xE1;s
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>BR,Brazil: Serie B</td>

                                            <td>01:30</td>
                                            <td class="text-right">
                                                S&#xE3;o Bento
                                                <img src="https://secure.cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/6120.png" height="20" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">1 - 0</td>
                                            <td class="text-left">
                                                <img src="https://secure.cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/322.png" height="20" />
                                                Paysandu
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>BR,Brazil: Serie B</td>

                                            <td>01:30</td>
                                            <td class="text-right">
                                                Juventude
                                                <img src="https://secure.cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/314.png" height="20" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">0 - 1</td>
                                            <td class="text-left">
                                                <img src="https://secure.cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/305.png" height="20" />
                                                Crici&#xFA;ma
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>BR,Brazil: Serie B</td>

                                            <td>00:15</td>
                                            <td class="text-right">
                                                Ava&#xED;
                                                <img src="https://secure.cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/330.png" height="20" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">1 - 0</td>
                                            <td class="text-left">
                                                <img src="https://secure.cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/344.png" height="20" />
                                                CRB
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End card-body -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see I wrapped the `sidebar` and the `datatables` html inside a `row`(which is also inside a `container-fluid`) for have the elements in one row. Then, I created two columns to create the responsive layout, the problem is that I get the following:

[image]

As you can see the sidebar doesn't go to the left side of the `datatables` but goes to the top, and this is wrong.

I created a [JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/2203/).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code isn't working in the JS Fiddle because you have bootstrap 3 included and not bootstrap 4. If you fix your import to bootstrap 4 it works: http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/2202/

Comment: sorry I fix the link, same problem with v4

Comment: it works in the link i posted above

Comment: @ratherblue nope it doesn't works because the sidebar must be at the left side not on the top

Answer (score 1):

Add the stylesheet into your `<head>` and it seems to work fine with the menu bar on the left as expected.

> https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

If you check the console, you'll see that the bootstrap stylings weren't showing up from the link you provided.